# SwiftUI TextField kerning/tracking?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uitextfield, swiftui-text

I am very new to SwiftUI and I am trying to add kerning to TextField in SwiftUI and can't figure out how. Can anybody help, can't even figure out what to write more in this post.